# Starting actvity with animation when pressing listview item

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-activity

I am trying to start an activity with activityOptions to animate transition when selecting item from `listview` activity. only `startActivity(intent)` method is available. (trying to call `startActivity(intent,bundle)` gives compile time error when called from `onItemClick` method of `listview` activity.

Any ideas how can i generate a transition effect when starting an activtiy if a list item from listview is selected?

Thanks.

My mistake. i didnot converted activityOption to bundle. Now its OK.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I use overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide, R.anim.slide2); something like this